# [Debian][Apache2] Working LDAP connection on our AD, how do I add SSO?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache2, debian, single-sign-on

> I'm very sorry, if the question is already here anywhere, but I
>   searched for hours and didn't find anything. Perhaps I only don't
>   know, for what exactly I have to search.

In the Intranet of the company, where I'm doing my trainee, I have implemented an LDAP Directory Protection to the Apache Webserver (Based on Debian 7).

(Like that: http://technedigitale.com/archives/254)

Is it now possible, to add SSO on top of it? and if it's possible, how?

I always find SSO via Kerberos, do I have to use it and really can't use my existing one and add SSO?

Thank you so much,

Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Kerberos will be better (less complex) approach to achieve SSO. Also, Users in intranet will not require to submit credentials manually.